# How can I control the Java version used with Ammonite

Tags: scala, ammonite

In my Linux system I have several Java versions installed.
How can I control the version used to launch an Ammonite script?

Comment: Have you tried changing the **JAVA_HOME** env var?

Comment: I think JAVA_HOME isn't used.

Comment: I don't test it, but it looks great (if your project is not very secure)
[How to Install Multiple Versions of Java](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-java-on-the-sa)

Comment: CentOS, Ubuntu and all major Linux distributions allow to install several versions of Java at once, but only one in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The `amm` executable is a sh script.
It searches `java` in the `PATH`.
So you can change temporarily your `PATH`.  In bash it can be done in this way:

```
PATH=/path/to/java myscript.sc argument1 argument2 ....
```